# Continuity and differentiability of functions

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Show that

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq |f'(x_0)||x-x_0|.$$

I don't know whether differentiability of $f$ on $(a,b)$ is needed in assumption.

I just have seen this question in a part of a paper in the class, so I did not know exactly this is the question or something is missing.

Could anyone tell me what is this and how to start solving it.

Comment: This statement is not true

Comment: You need some convexity assumption on $f$, I think

Comment: Does anyone know the correct form of this question.

Comment: Yes. Assuming the function is decreasing or increasing on the interval $[a,b]$ and $x, x_0\in (a,b)$ then the opposite is true ($\ge$ instead of $\le $).

Comment: Sorry I read it wrong. Misread where u evaluated the derivative. However added conditions must be asserted

Answer (score 0):

This statement is true, provided you assert that $f$ is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$, as well as $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$. Then it can be said that 
$$|f(x) - f(x_0)|\le |f'(x_0)(x-x_0)|$$
EDIT:
I have found a contradiction. I will work on fixing this when I am on a computer.

Comment: Could you please be able to write some steps proving this inequality?

Comment: What if the derivative of $f$ happens to be $0$ at $x_0$ but not elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false. There is a counterexample.

Consider the function $f(x) = x^2 $, and $x_0 = 0$

We have $f'(x) = 2x \implies f'(x_0) = 0$

The statement then reads :

$$
|x^2-0| \leq 0\times |x-0|
$$

Or,

$$x^2 \leq 0$$

Which is false for $x\neq0$.